# request-promise - How can I get the result from a Promise outside of the function?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `request-promise` and I have this piece of code

```
func = (a) => {
  request(`http://somewebsite.com/${a}`).then((response) => response)
}
```

What I want to know is how can I get the response when I call `func(a)`? I mean, how can I get the response object from that? For example:

```
var b = func('path');
console.log(b) // Show me the response object, instead it shows undefined.
```

How can I access the response outside of the promise?

Comment: You can't, but you can return a promise and add another `then` function

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have an `async/await` similar to languages like `C#`. You need to access the data inside of a callback.

Comment: Although you are currently correct, JavaScript [soon will have `async` and `await` keywords](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/)